# No. of subsites in a site collection?

Tags: powershell, site-collection, site

How to get number of subsites in a site collection using Powershell?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

or simply:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://YourSharePointSite
$site.AllWebs.Count
```

Comment: @BennySkogberg: Thanks! At least, it is simple, and that is often the most important when we need the answer quickly.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1) {$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"} 
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$sites = Get-SPSite <SiteCollectionUrl>   
$noOfWebs = 0

foreach ($web in $sites.AllWebs)
{
    $noOfWebs++
}

If ($sites -ne $null)
{
    $sites.Dispose();
}

If ($web -ne $null)
{
    $web.Dispose();
}

Write-Host "Total No of Subsites: " $noOfWebs
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the following code, within the SharePoint Management Shell, you can get the count of Web Applications in the Farm, Site Collections in Web Application, Sites in Site Collection.

```
Write-Host "Web Applications in Farm"
$WebApplications = Get-SPWebApplication
$WebApplications | Measure-Object | Format-List Count

ForEach($WebApplication in $WebApplications) {
    Write-Host "Site Collections in the Web Application named " $WebApplication.Name
    $WebApplication.Sites | Measure-Object | Format-List Count

    ForEach($SiteCollection in $WebApplication.Sites) {
        Write-Host "Webs (Sub-Sites) in the Site Collection with the URL " $SiteCollection.Url
        Write-Host "`nCount : " $SiteCollection.AllWebs.Count "`n`n`n"    
    }    
}
```